# not load javascript in ajax layer by

Tags: javascript, ajax

Turns out I using ajax to change contents of a div to change and show me different sliders, here I pass the files if you can take a look, I have days trying to find answers for the network and trying unsuccessfully codes.

Files: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27792874/ejemplo.rar

Ajax code:

```
 <script>
function nuevoAjax(){

    var xmlhttp=false;
    try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
    try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
    xmlhttp = false;
    }
    }

    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;

} 



function Cargar(url){


var centro_galeria = document.getElementById('centro_galeria'); 


ajax=nuevoAjax(); 
ajax.open("GET", url,true); 

ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){

if(ajax.readyState==4){


centro_galeria.innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

}

}

ajax.send(null);




}


</script>
```

Comment: You should post your code in the question itself. If you remove your link the question becomes meaningless and is of no value to anyone else.

Comment: The code is long, so I've put in a rar. I will if I WANT the ajax code, sorry for my English is google translator.

Comment: Sorry, I have set the ajax code that is to be loaded into the content div which I think is responsible. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it and read code - and I have following advice: Do not mix jQuery with *old* technics.

This code seems be correct

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#slider1').cycle({
    fx: 'fade', //'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight,scrollUp',blindX, blindY, blindZ, cover, curtainX, curtainY, fade, fadeZoom, growX, growY, none, scrollUp,scrollDown,scrollLeft,scrollRight,scrollHorz,scrollVert,shuffle,slideX,slideY,toss,turnUp,turnDown,turnLeft,turnRight,uncover,ipe ,zoom
    speed:  '600', 
    timeout: '7000',
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev',
    pager:  '#thumb',
       pauseOnHover: false,                 // if you hover pauses the slider
        startClockOnMouseOut: false,        // if clock should start on MouseOut


    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="43" height="29" /></a></li>'; 
    }  
});
});
```

But

```
function nuevoAjax(){

var xmlhttp=false;
try {
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
try {
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (E) {
xmlhttp = false;
}
}

if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return xmlhttp;   
}
```

and

```
function Cargar(url){
var centro_galeria = document.getElementById('centro_galeria'); 

ajax=nuevoAjax(); 
ajax.open("GET", url,true); 

ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){

if(ajax.readyState==4){
     $.getScript("js/jquery.min.js");
$.getScript("js/jquery.cycle.all.js");

centro_galeria.innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

}
}     
ajax.send(null);
}
```

clashes each other - because you combine function for ajax written in *old* technics with jQuery ajax technics.

I think that most problem is this code:

```
ajax=nuevoAjax(); 
ajax.open("GET", url,true);
```

because `.open('GET', url, true)` is jQuery's matter - but `ajax=nuevoAjax();` is classic matter

Solution would be: use only jQuery ajax technics. And of course, if you have already linked jQuery in `<head>` section of page, you don't need to call it via else ajax again.

Comment: Thank you very much, the fact is that the code works perfectly, but I will look these failures, do you think the problem may be to not load the javascript slider? Thank you very much for your prompt response!

Comment: I used jquery and the method of this product without success, does not work me.  Http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/uso-AJAX-jquery.html